# Как назвать состояние человека в описанной ситуации?

Tags: терминология

Давно ещё слышал историю. Вот она:

> Аэропорт, посадки, запах кофе разносится по всему помещению. На
>   скамейке сидит мужчина, а рядом бегает ребенок, и сразу видно, что он
>   сынишка этого мужчины. Бегает, балуется, то перепрыгнет через
>   скамейку, то пролезет под ней. Эти деяния раздражают рядом сидящих
>   людей, те шепчутся, якобы отец балует ребенка. В то время отец ребенка
>   сидит, опустив глаза и наблюдая, как отблески на полу переливаются. На
>   нем нету ни радости, ни печали. Но вот один посторонний человек решил
>   сделать замечание. Диалог был такой.     — Сэр, вы можете сказать
>   своему сыну, чтобы он прекратил себя так вести?   — Ой, простите,
>   пожалуйста, просто у меня умерла жена, а у мальчика его мать. Поэтому
>   я растерян и не проследил за ним. Сейчас скажу ему, чтоб не баловался.
>   Человек, который решил сделать замечание, почувствовал ком в горле —
>   не зная обстоятельств, решил высказаться.

Как назвать состояние героя, сделавшего замечание, и ситуацию в целом?

Comment: @shampar, Дмитрий фактически задал два вопроса: "Как назвать описанную ситуацию в целом?" и "Как называется состояние человека в этой истории?". Кто-то отвечал на первый вопрос, кто-то на второй. А Вы убрали первый вопрос совсем.

Comment: Да, это два вопроса. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> Как называется состояние человека в этой истории?

Тот, кто сделал замечание, был смущен, сконфужен, расстороен, испытывал чувство неловкости, вины.

> Как назвать описанную ситуацию в целом?

Если одним словом, то **конфуз** (неловкое положение).

> [КОНФУЗ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D1%83%D0%B7), -а; м. [от лат. cōnfūsio - беспорядок, замешательство; смущение] Состояние смущения, неловкости; неловкое положение. **Вышел, случился, получился к**. Обещания своего он не сдержал, к великому своему конфузу. <Конфузный (см.).

Answer (score 1):

Ситуацию, в которую попал человек, сделавший замечание, можно охарактеризовать одним словом: **неловкость**. Или можно сказать, что этот человек **попал в неловкую ситуацию**. Есть много других синонимичных выражений, но с учётом обстоятельств для описания данной ситуации лучше использовать наиболее нейтральное, без неуместного здесь юмора, злословия, сарказма и т. п.

[**НЕЛОВКОСТЬ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x), -и; ж. ...
2. Неловкий, неудачный поступок; что-л. неудачно, **неуместно сказанное**. Сгладить н. Извиниться за допущенную н. Совершить ряд неловкостей. 3. Чувство неловкости, смущения. Испытывать н. Стараться побороть свою н.

Comment: Ну да,  можно ещё сказать конфуз.

Comment: "Замешательство" ещё подойдёт здесь.

Comment: Поступок неловкий, ситуация нелепая.

Answer (score 0):

Уау.

*[Прострация](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&all=x)* это называется.

На московском диалекте - *пребывать в своём сюжете*.

---

ПыСы.

Это я нечаянно про героя сюжета, а творец замечаний -  эмпат, человек с развитой способностью к [эмпатии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F). Он просто устыдился.

Comment: Да, стыд еще никто не упомянул.

Comment: Спасибо, друг, ты настоящий товарищ и брат.